# EmguCV: Problem using multiple identical cameras

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, camera, emgucv

I am using EmguCV to get images from different webcams but my program fails only when I use two identical cameras. I have 4 cameras in total: a webcam built-in in the PC, an external webcam, and two USB microscopes which are identical.

In the code I create two video captures to grab images from two different sources and display them in two picture boxes. It works fine with every combination of cameras, except when I use the two microscopes, which are same brand and model.

```
Dim index0 As Integer = 0 'Select camera to display in picturebox 1
Dim index1 As Integer = 1 'Select camera to display in picturebox 2
Dim cap0 As New VideoCapture(index0)   
Dim cap1 As New VideoCapture(index1)   

Private Sub btnSelect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click
    Timer1.Start()  'Start timer
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'For each tick of the timer display camera capture into imageBox
    Dim frame As Mat = cap0.QueryFrame()
    Dim frame1 As Mat = cap1.QueryFrame()
    pbCam0.Image = frame.Bitmap
    pbCam1.Image = frame1.Bitmap
End Sub
```

In index0 and index1 I introduce the index value of the camera I want to connect: (0) internal webcam, (1) external webcam, (2) USB microscope and (3) USB microscope.
When I use the combination of the two microscopes (2-3 or 3-2), whichever of both I assign to cap1 won't display the image. cap1.QueryFrame returns an empty frame. The error message I get when try to display the image in pbCam1 is:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

If anyone got a similar problem or knows the reason why this happens I will appreciate any help!

Many thanks

EDIT: I found out the problem might be that I use a USB hub (4 USB3.0 ports, with external power supply 12V/3A). When connecting one microscope to the hub and the other directly to the laptop port, it works.

I don't know why with some cameras it's fine connecting two of them through the hub but with others it is not. Maybe some cameras need more power and the hub can't supply two at the same time? Or maybe it's a problem with the drivers?

Comment: Are the IP address set different on the two cameras?  I think the connection is closing.  Make sure the camera software is update from vendor site incase it is an issue with the camera.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to verify the connection closed [FIN].  You can also check status of connection from cmd.exe >Netstat -a

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jdweng. I found out a possible cause. My laptop only has two USB ports so I use a USB hub. Because I had problems before with cheap USB hubs, I bought one with external power supply (4 USB3.0 ports, 12V/3A). I tried to connect one microscope to the hub and the other directly to the laptop USB port and it works fine.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were connecting by IP or USB.  You cannot connect two cameras to the same USB (com port number).  You need two different com number.